# Symfony 5 : could not find driver

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, mysql-connector

I'm using symfony 5, everything works fine when I do a command line migration (ex: `php bin/console make:migration`), but when I try to save a form in code with `$doctrine->flush();` I get an error `"An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver"`
I'm using `mysql`,

my config:

in my `.env` file i have :

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/myecom?serverVersion=10.4.11-MariaDB"
```

my `doctrine.yaml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
     # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

my controller:

```
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $doctrine->persist($user);

            $doctrine->flush();
```

Do you have any hint to debug this?

**EDIT : Resolved**

The problem is that the php version of apache (php 7.2) is not supported by doctrine which requires php > 7.3, I put apache on php 7.3 and it works, to do it I proceeded as follows:

Disable the current php version:

```
sudo a2dismod php7.2
```

Restart apache:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Enable php 7.3:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

Restart Symfony server:

```
php bin/console server:stop
php bin/console server:start
```

Comment: Use `phpinfo();` or `php -m` to see if PDO driver is installed or not.

Comment: Yes I did and I see that it is installed correctly

Comment: What's the output of `symfony php -m`? can you see  `pdo` and `pdo_mysql`?

Comment: yes both are installed

Comment: it appears that you have different php for cli and www

Comment: @YourCommonSense how can you know it ? and how can i resolve this please ?

Comment: I know it from the very description you posted above. And the link to the similar question is pinned at the top of this question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense indeed, the difference of the php versions poses problem, I corrected it, thank you very much